# How to run nodejs with apollo graphql server

Tags: node.js, express, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

Hi I am using Apollo GraphQL server, mongodb, nodejs in my application. I have schema and resolvers and movies.js

schema.js

```
const typeDefs = `
    type Movie {
         _id: Int!
        name: String!
    }
    type Query {
        mv: [Movie]
    }
`;
module.exports = typeDefs;
```

resolvers.js

```
const mongoDB = require("../mongoose/connect");

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    mv: async (root, args, context) => {
      return await mongoDB.connectDB(async err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const db = mongoDB.getDB();
        db
          .collection("movie")
          .find({})
          .toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            return JSON.stringify(result);
            db.close();
          });
      });
    }
  }
};
module.exports = resolvers;
```

movie.js

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { graphqlExpress } = require("apollo-server-express");
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require("graphql-tools");

const createResolvers = require("../graphql/resolvers");
const typeDefs = require("../graphql/schema");
const resolvers = require("../graphql/resolvers");

var router = express.Router();

const executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

router.get(
  "/",
  bodyParser.json(),
  graphqlExpress({
    executableSchema
  })
);

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var graph = require("./routes/movie");
app.use("/movie", movie);
```

When I try to access it http://localhost/movie then I am getting this error GET query missing.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/movie` is declared as a GraphQL endpoint, so you have to send a (GraphQL) query to it.

With `GET` endpoints, you'd do that by passing the query as a (URL-escaped) query parameter:

```
http://localhost/movie?query=...
```

(documented here: http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/apollo-server/requests.html#getRequests)

To post the query `{ mv { name } }`, the URL would become this:

```
http://localhost:3000/movie?query=%7B%20mv%20%7B%20name%20%7D%20%7D
```

But I would suggest setting up a `POST` endpoint so you can send [`POST` requests](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/apollo-server/requests.html#postRequests).

Additionally, you're passing an incorrect property name to `graphqlExpress`, it should be this:

```
router.get(
  "/",
  bodyParser.json(),
  graphqlExpress({
    schema : executableSchema
  })
);
```

Comment: I am using this http://localhost:3000/graph?query=query{mv[{name}]} and getting `{"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error GraphQL request (1:9) Expected Name, found [\n\n1: query{mv[{name}]}\n           ^\n","locations":[{"line":1,"column":9}]}]}`

Comment: See `{"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error GraphQL request (1:1) Cannot parse the unexpected character \"%\".\n\n1: %7B%20mv%20%7B%20name%20%7%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BD%20%7D\n   ^\n","locations":[{"line":1,"column":1}]}]}`

Comment: @Nancy see my updated answer. There were some hidden characters in the URL I posted that shouldn't be there, and I also found another issue.

Comment: Thanks. mv is of type array. Should it { mv [ { name} ] } ? I tried to log result of resolver `db
          .collection("movie")
          .find({})
          .toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            return JSON.stringify(result);
            db.close();
          });` it prints `[ { _id: 59ba279e0a605b4a3bf93e76, name: 'Iron Man', year: 2017 } ]` but it sends to client `{"data":{"mv":null}}` Something wrong in my resolver async or await ?

Comment: @Nancy try returning `result` without calling `JSON.stringify()` on it. Also, `db.close()` will never get called because you return before it. Oh, and you're mixing callbacks with promises in your resolver, also not a good thing. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154460/discussion-between-nancy-and-robertklep).